# Python: simple list modify task

Tags: list, python-3.x

I need to remove the unique elements of the list, the first thought is:

```
def cut_uniq(data):
    for x in data:
        if data.count(x) == 1:
            data.remove(x)
    print(data)

cut_uniq([1, 2, 3, 4, 5,])
```

return

```
[2, 4]
```

please, tell me why?

Comment: E2BIG: Too many duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at each iteration:

```
  i   x     data
  0   1   [1,2,3,4,5]
  1   3   [2,3,4,5]
  2   5   [2,4,5] 
          [2,4]
```

You can iterate over a different list than you are modifying. This returns a copy of the list

```
def cut_uniq(data):
    return [x for x in data if data.count(x) > 1]
```

or more efficiently

```
from collection import Counter
def cut_uniq(data):
    return [x for x, count in Counter(data) if count > 1]
```

If you really do want to modify the original list, and not return a copy

```
def cut_uniq(data):
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        if data.count(data[i]) == 1:
            del data[i]
        else:
            i += 1
```

or

```
from collections import Counter
def cut_uniq(data):
    for x, count in Counter(data):
        if count == 1:
            data.remove(x)
```

95% of the time that you modify the same list as you're iterating over, you'll have problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
for x in data:
```

it translates to

for i in [0,1,2,3,4]:
   x = data[i]

So in the first loop, i = 0 data[i]=1. you remove 1 from data, the data is [2,3,4,5]

on the second loop , i = 1, because now data is [2,3,4,5], data[i] = 3. So 2 is left in the data list and never been visited.

Same as the number 4.

So when you finished your loop, the [2,4] leted in the list.